Expand nodejs socket size
I have a tcp proxy server in nodejs and it uses the net module. Sometimes large packets come through and then the server just crashes. I tried finding out how to expand the socket size online and from chatgpt but i cant find a solution.
How can i fix this?
I already tried this
socket.highWaterMark = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB
socket._server.highWaterMark = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB
socket.bufferSize = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB
socket.writableLength = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB
socket._writableState.highWaterMark = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB
socket._readableState.highWaterMark = 0.25 * 1024 ** 2; // 256KB


What makes you believe, the socket size is the problem? How did the server crash? Do you get an error message?

"… and then the server just crashes" - crashes how?

I get an EECONRESET error. i think its due to something limiting what it can receive because when a packet exceeds a certain size (~60kb) it will crash.
